# Per request lifetime of ApplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net

Cannot seem to get the ApplicationDbContext using this code

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The error says that no overloaded method for Get() uses 0 arguments. Not sure what parameter to pass.

I am trying to use the same ApplicationDbContext that OWIN has a link to, instead of creating an additional one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Get() method without any parameters is defined as an extension method in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` namespace. To get this to compile, add the following using statement:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```